# Capistrano v3 - Hook to run command post deploy

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I am using Capistrano to deploy to a server running Nginx. I'm running into some issues with APC and I need to reload PHP-FPM after Capistrano has completed the deployment.  The issue [itself is outlined here](https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/restart-php-fpm-during-deployments/)  but like that author I don't want to have to SSH in and reload PHP-FPM remotely from the command line, I'd like Capistrano to do it as a post deployment hook.

The essence of the deploy.rb being used is below;

```
    set :application, "deploytest"

    set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:gitaccount/git-repo.git"
    set :scm,         :git
    set :deploy_via,  :remote_cache
    set :app_webroot, "/public"

    default_run_options[:pty] = true

    desc "Execute Capistrano tasks against Production server."
    task :prod do
        role :web, "123.45.67.89"
        role :app, "123.45.67.89"
        set :env,         "prod"
        set :domain,      "deploy-domain.com"
        set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/vhosts/#{domain}/site"
        set :branch,      "master"
    end
```

And I can push using the command;

```
    bundle exec cap prod deploy
```

Works great.  Boy have I struggled trying to get that command to automatically trigger another command once the deploy is complete.

**What I have tried;**

Here's a summary of the main approaches;

1. Creating a new namespace for my task

   ```
   namespace :mcnab do
     desc "Running hook post deploy"
     task :fpmreload do
       execute "service php-fpm reload"
     end
   end

   after "deploy:create_symlink", "mcnab:fpmreload"
   ```
2. Wrapping both tasks in a 'deploy' namespace and using the following command to trigger the hook

   ```
   after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:fpmreload"
   ```
3. Explicitly setting the roles again within the new task

   ```
   task :fpmreload do
       role :web, "178.62.13.10"
       role :app, "178.62.13.10"
       on roles(:all) do 
           execute "service php-fpm reload"
       end  
   end
   ```
4. Setting the user explicitly

   ```
   task :fpmreload do
     on "user@123.45.67.89" do
       execute "service php-fpm reload"
     end
   end
   ```
5. Using 'run' instead of execute

   ```
   task :fpmreload do
     on "user@123.45.67.89" do
       run "service php-fpm reload"
     end
   end
   ```

Hrrmph, and about a million variations thereon. I'm really just guessing now, even with verbose error reporting the error messages are not helping much. Just one working example of a deploy.rb file with a simple post deploy hook running a command would be great but I can't find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me

```
before :published, :fpm_reload
desc 'Fpm reload'
task :fpm_reload do
  on release_roles :all do |host|
    execute :service, 'php5-fpm', :reload
  end
end
```

The docs:
http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/

Comment: What an unexpected pleasant surprise after 6 months!  Good on you sir.  Can I just clarify, I take it `|host|` is the IP address wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: the `host` is an instance of Capistrano::Configuration::Server    to get the ip/host you can do `host.hostname` http://www.rubydoc.info/github/capistrano/capistrano/Capistrano/Configuration/Server