# Capistrano and systemd integration

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3, systemd

I'd like to keep my unit files in source control (e.g. in `config`), such that after a capistrano deploy, the unit will be copied to the `systemd` dir, and the service (e.g. puma) will be restarted. What would be the best way to achieve this?

I've thought simply adding [a post-deploy task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30191727/165753) such as (untested code)

```
namespace :deploy do
[...]

  before :published, :systemd
  desc 'systemd'
  task :systemd do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      within release_path do
        execute "sudo cp config/puma.service /etc/systemd/system/puma.service"
        execute "sudo cp config/puma-init /usr/bin/puma-init"
        execute "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"
        execute "sudo systemctl restart puma"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, but I still wonder if there's a more elegant solution

```
namespace :deploy do
  [...]

  before :published, :systemd
  desc 'systemd integration'
  task :systemd do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      within shared_path do
        execute "sudo cp #{shared_path}/config/puma.service /etc/systemd/system/puma.service"
        execute "sudo cp #{shared_path}/config/puma-init /usr/bin/puma-init"
        execute "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"
        execute "sudo systemctl restart puma"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, note that you need to

```
set :pty, true
```

Otherwise `sudo` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like what you've described in your example will work. As an alternative, what I've done is create a symlink.

To do so, I'd suggest moving your service files to something like `config/systemd/` in your repo. Deploy once, then create a symlink on the server like `ln -s $CURRENT_PATH/config/systemd/ /etc/systemd/system/myapp`. Now when you deploy, the path the symlink is pointing to will change (due to the Capistrano managed `current` symlink), and you just have to restart the processes.

Comment: Thanks, could you share the full code for your task? I recall systemd having issues with symlinks, but perhaps it was resolved in recent versions.